# Simple deform does not bend the whole mesh

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to bend a rather simple mesh (originally a cube but stretched out and flattened) with simple deform - bend in a -45 degree angle using an empty in the z-axis as origin. Why does it only bend a face and not the whole mesh?

Best

Staffan

bend

[image: bend]

Comment: hello, it looks like it bends the whole mesh, what is your initial mesh and what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: My initial mesh was a cube. I stretched it so that it became an outstretched cuboid, like a "flat stick". I want that stick to bend in one of its ends.

Comment: it can only bend if it has enough topology to bend, does it? also, maybe rotate it 90° on Z

Comment: Yes, I added several loopcuts to the mesh.

Comment: also in Edit mode rotate it 90° on Z so it is aligned along X

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It did get better by using them. However it turned out it was not really what I wanted. I found this tutorial. The instructions at 3 min was very helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kNUkxg2b8E